# How can I execute a function when i pass data between siblings components?

Tags: reactjs

I have three components: a parent and two siblings

in the parent

```
this.state = {
  data: ""
}
change = () => {
  this.setState({data: "newData"})
  //trave.AddData()
}
render(){
  return (
    <div>
        <Data execute={this.change}/>
        <Travel data={this.state.data}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

in Data component:

```
onSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.change();
    }
```

and in my Travel component, i have a function AddData()

```
this.state= {
      blows:[]
    }

    AddData() {
        console.log("i dont see", this.props);
        this.setState({
    blows:[...this.state.blows, this.props.data]
  })
```

i want to execute that function

Comment: You are directly mutating the state.
You need to use `setState` for updating your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you directly mutate the state directly (`this.state.data=xxxxx`), the component will not cause any re-render. The correct way to update state in class component is to use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

```js
this.state = {
  data: ""
}
change = () => {
  // this.state.data="newData" // <---dont do this
  this.setState({data: "newData"})
}
render(){
  return (
    <div>
        <Data execute={this.change}/>
        <Travel data={this.state.data}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly pass data between siblings. You have to make `parent` as an intermediary component. So you need to pass to the parent from child-1 and then pass the data to child-2 from parent as `props`.

you can take a look at [this](https://blog.codecarrot.net/passing-data-between-react-components/).

and also `setState` takes object as argument, and you can't assign value with `=` operator.

`this.setState({ data: value });`